# how to have a css in javascript when onsubmit trigger in another window?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
function welcome() {
    var Name = document.getElementById("name").value; 

    var form = "<h1>" + "HI  " + Name  + " READY YOUR REFLEXES!" + "</h1>";
    document.write(form);
    return false;
}
```

how to have a css in javascript when `onsubmit` trigger in another window?

Comment: java != javascript... and javascript knows nothing about css. if you want css, then add it: `'<h1 class="foo">H1 <span style="color: puce;">' + name + '</span></h1>'`

Comment: A couple of things to help write better questions: Your question title should match your question body. Please format your code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being quick : 
A way for adding a style to your inserted title is to add a class to it :

```
var form = "<h1 class='myclass'>HI  " + Name  + " READY YOUR REFLEXES!" + "</h1>";
```

Then create a css rule:

```
.myclass{color:red;}
```

```js
     
    function welcome(){
      var Name = document.getElementById("name").value; 
      
      //var form = "<h1>" + "HI  " + Name  + " READY YOUR REFLEXES!" + "</h1>";
      var form = "<h1 class='myclass'>HI  " + Name  + " READY YOUR REFLEXES!" + "</h1>";
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=form;
      return false;    
    }
```

```css
      .myclass{color:red;}
```

```html
    <button type="button" onclick="welcome()" value="Welcome">Welcome</button>
      <input id="name" type="text" value="">
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: my bad, i didn't see that direct writing to document was disabling the styles. So the correct way is to put your content via innerHTML property, instead of the write function.

Comment: I need your help sir/maam. Please help me it helps a lot. Thank you. Here's the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38755036/how-to-collide-same-ball-color-with-the-2-ball-that-can-rotate-when-it-click-or

Comment: The required field doesn't work when I code it. How can I required the input using your given code? Thank you.